# How to use break statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a working currency converter in 2.7 but I want to make sure the program doesn't get data it can't process put in by the user.

1. how to get user input to be understood irrelevant of case
2. how to get the program to restart if user input is wrong; i.e. a break if but I couldn't work out how to do this despite searching around and testing a few a methods.

I have left the rest of the code as it is insignificant effectively duplicate of the first set of multiplication using the preset figures.

```
currency = str(raw_input ("""what currency would you like to covert: GBP, EURO, USD OR YEN?
"""))
exchange = str(raw_input("""what currency would you like in exchange? : GBP, EURO, USD OR YEN?
                              """))
amount = int(input("""how much would you like to convert?
                      """))
decision = str(raw_input("""Please enter u for user input exchange rate or s for the preset exchange rate
"""))

if decision == "u" :
    user_rate = raw_input("Please enter the current exchange rate")
    exchange_value = int(amount) *  int(user_rate)
    print ("At the user found exchange rate you will receive",exchange_value,exchange)

elif decision == "s" :
    if currency  == "GBP" and exchange == "USD":
        exchange_value= int(amount) * 1.6048
        print ("At the preset exchange rate you will receive",exchange_value,exchange)

    if currency  == "GBP" and exchange == "EUR":
        exchange_value= int(amount) * 1.2399
        print ("At the preset exchange rate you will receive",exchange_value,exchange)
```

Comment: There's no loop.  You can't `break` out of a non-loop.

Comment: Unrelated: `str(raw_input(...))` is redundant, because `raw_input` returns a string. `int(input())` should be `int(raw_input())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will help you to get started

```
    valid_input = ('EUR', 'GBP', 'USD', 'JPY')

    while True:
        # Obtain user data

        # Make sure all its in caps
        currency = currency.upper()
        exchange = exchange.upper()

        if currency in valid_input and exchange in valid_input:
            break 

         print ("Error Invalid input, try again...")

    # Proccess data...
```

Answer (score 2):

1) You can compare the user input string using the same case regardless

`if currency.lower() == 'gbp'`

or

`if currency.upper() == 'GBP'`

2) You could run your program in a while loop, that way if a condition is not met you can `continue` to the next iteration of the loop (which would restart your program from the beginning)

```
while True:
  # get user input
  # validate user input
  # if input not valid continue, which will "restart" your program
```

Comment: thanks for the answer in regards to the second part is there a function to say while no errors? so e.g while true =  errors: restart program