# break and pass functions are not processing correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7

The functions break and pass don't appear to work with correct input the program stops and with out correct input the program decides not to break but to print the string telling the user that there is a problem and carry on running.

```
currency = str(raw_input ("""what currency would you like to covert: GBP, EURO, USD OR YEN?
"""))


exchange = str(raw_input("""what currency would you like in exchange? : GBP, EURO, USD OR YEN?
                              """))

amount = int(input("""how much would you like to convert?
                      """))



valid_input = ('EUR','eur','GBP','gbp' ,'USD','usd','JPY','jpy')

while True:

    if currency in valid_input and exchange in valid_input:

        pass

    else:

        print("incorrect input, please restart program")
        break


decision = str(raw_input("""Please enter u for user input exchange rate or s for the preset exchange rate
    """))


if decision == "u" :
    user_rate = raw_input("Please enter the current exchange rate")

    exchange_value = int(amount) *  int(user_rate)

    print ("At the user found exchange rate you will receive",exchange_value,exchange)



    elif decision == "s" :


    if currency  == "GBP" and exchange == "USD":

        exchange_value= int(amount) * 1.6048

        print ("At the preset exchange rate you will receive",exchange_value,exchange)

    if currency  == "GBP" and exchange == "EUR":

        exchange_value= int(amount) * 1.2399

        print ("At the preset exchange rate you will receive",exchange_value,exchange)
```

Comment: http://ideone.com/8vQvQi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `break` statement breaks out of your loop, continuing on with the rest of the program. If you want to exit the program instead, use something like [`sys.exit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

`pass` doesn't do anything at all; it's a placeholder for an empty block. As you're using it, it basically causes your loop to loop forever. *That* is where you meant to use `break`.

Comment: +1. I wonder why he has a while loop in the first place though (as he tells the user to restart).

Comment: Because of an answer to [his previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499213/how-to-use-break-statement), I guess. I assume this code is a work in progress rather than an instance of cargo cult programming.

Comment: @userwill: you don't have to restart the whole program, you just have to prompt for user input again.

Answer (score -2):

"break" works only insinde switch and for/while

Comment: and you must put a parentheses

Comment: Python doesn't have a switch statement, and his break *is* inside a while block.